# Drupal EFQ propertyOrderBy with integer as title

Tags: entities

I have an EFQ where I'm getting a list of store nodes according to the logged-in rep's (user) territory. It's working well, except the propertyOrderBy is returning the node titles ordered only by the first number in the title string. The titles are store numbers. i.e. 954, 980, 8475, etc.

```
  // Get the stores for the logged-in user's territory code.
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'store')
    ->fieldCondition('field_territory', 'target_id', $terr, '=')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->propertyOrderBy('title', 'DESC');
  $result = $query->execute();
```

The list is being returned DESC as requested, but only by the first number. In this case, 9 -> 8 -> 6, whereas it should be ordered by the whole number string, 8475 -> 6905 -> 6903 -> 980 -> 954. Below is what it looks like now. Any ideas how to order properly?

```
    STORE #
    980
    954
    8475
    6905
    6903
```

Comment: This is because the Title field is of type "varchar". And if you order a varchar type then it naturally gets sorted like that (Alphabetical ordering - 9 is more than 8, no matter how many figures, or decimals, it's still treated as a string). You can either cast it as int in MySQL (use db_query instead of EFQ), or you have to change your design, and have a `Store ID` field, instead of using the title field for that purpose.